# gflags doesn't work in 64 bit Windows 7, but 32 bit environment

Tags: debugging, windbg, gflags

I'm trying to debug a 32 bit program on 64 bit Windows 7.

So I use gflags to set the debugger for that app. I fill in the path of the application, and the one of the debugger. But when I start the application, WinDBG doesn't run.

The same configuration works on 32 bit Windows 7.

So, is it impossible to debug a 32 bit application on 64 bit environment?

Comment: Yes you can debug, you can set the effective machine from WinDbg 64-bit using `.effmach x86`. Is it possible the path is incorrect?

Comment: Hi @EdChum I mean that when I double click on the application, I want to start a windbg session that debugs the program, rather than running the app. So I think a command running inside windbg might not help

Comment: @EdChum The path is correct, when I hit on `Launch` it starts

Comment: could you check the following registry key if it is correct: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ImageFileName\Debugger`, it should list the path to Windbg.exe, beyond that I'm not sure what else to check as gflags puts these registry key values in and then the appropriate action occurs based on the reg values. There is more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it's possible that this is a limitation or bug

Comment: Did you ever get this solved as I am having the exact same problem..

Answer (score 3):

For me this has always worked, even if I use the "wrong" architecture gflags.

However Windbg must be in the PATH, or you must include path when you specify the debugger to gflags.

[image]

Comment: So if windbg is not in %PATH%, Windows would start the app directly?

Comment: I think there will be an error message,  NB: path should NOT be in the image file name.

Comment: Wait, I just remembered that I've used absolute path of both the debugger and the app

Comment: IIRC, I thought IFEO doesn't like spaces in the path to the debugger. Maybe try copying to a path without spaces? But you said it works on 32 bit Win7 so maybe spaces are not an issue.

Comment: Use Process Monitor to see what is really going on in terms of the registry and file system.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

This is an old question. Older versions of gflags used to store the settings in one of the locations:

`HTML\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`

or

`HTML\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`

Depending on which architecture you pick for gflags.exe, it will affect either 64 bit or 32 bit processes.

Apparently at some point (thanks, @Thomas Weller to point it out), Microsoft changed gflags behavior and now (November 2016) current version of gflags.exe writes to both 32-bit and 64-bit registry locations, irrespective of the architecture.

This is a bit of a problem, because I used to use to attach 32-bit debugger to 32-bit processes and 64-bit debugger to 64 bit processes with the same process name. Now I cannot use gflags for this. However the workaround is to directly modify registry keys under `Image File Execution Options`.

### Old Answer

Processor architecture of gflags.exe actually matters. If you use 64-bit version of Windows Debugging tools and launch gflags.exe from there, it will affect behavior of 64-bit applications. Similarly, if you use 32-bit version of Windows Debugging Tools and launch gflags.exe, it will affect 32-bit applications.

32-bit and 64-bit versions could be installed side-by-side. Pay close attention on bitness of application you are debugging and use the same architecture of the debugger/tools.

Comment: I've installed both x86 edition and x64 edition of Windbg, and I set the debugger for that 32 bit app with the gflags of each edition. Still doesn't work ;-(

Comment: This is wrong. You can check with Process Monitor that both versions access the same Registry key. Also: create a setting in 64 bit, then start the 32 bit version and type in the same executable name and the settings will be there.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, please see my updates for the change in gflags behavior.